# from rolle can we conclude the existence of a local extremal.

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f:[a,b]\longrightarrow \mathbb R$ continuous and derivable on $]a,b[$ s.t. $f(b)=f(a)$. Can I conclude the existence of a local extremum ? To me it looks obvious that yes, but I can't prove it. So is there a function that has all these condition and that doesn't have an extremal local ? I can find such function if there $c\in ]a,b[$ such that $f$ is not derivable, but if $f$ is derivable everywhere on $]a,b[$, I don't no neither how to prove it nor to give a counter example.

Comment: It follows from Weierstrass' Theorem, in fact.

Comment: As I got, it seems so.

Comment: @Guy: Bolzano weierstrass theorem ?

Comment: @MathBeginner No, the theorems here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extreme_value_theorem

Comment: It is in reverse. We prove Rolle's by using existence of local extremum. Continuity ensures that there is a global extremum and $f(a) = f(b)$ ensures that the global extremum is attained not at end-points but somewhere in the interior and thereby it becomes local.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you should change the title of your question. My comment to the question was based on the title "from Rolle can we conclude the existence of local extremum?". For this title the answer is NO!!

The Rolle's Theorem conclusion requires the existence of a local extremum. The hypotheses "$f$ is continuous on $[a, b]$ and $f(a) = f(b)$" together guarantee the existence of local extremum. Together with this guarantee and the fact that $f$ is differentiable in $(a, b)$ we get the conclusion that derivative $f'$ vanishes somewhere in $(a, b)$.